# How can I list children group names (and not IP's) under a parent group in ansible?

Tags: ansible

My inventory looks something like this

```
[parent:children]
group1
group2
group3

[group1]
10.10.10.10 
1.1.1.1

[group2]
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
```

And i want to list the child groups under parent i.e

```
group1
group2
group3
```

and not

```
10.10.10.10
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
```

Answer (score 0):

As of current Ansible version 2.3 this is not possible without writing custom code.